# Android Studio 4.1 First App: can't find AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

[android studio picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/galdq.png)

This is hopefully extremely easy. I'm trying to create my first app in Android Studio, but there is no AndroidManifest.xml, or a "manifests" folder for my project. The tutorial I'm using (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project) is using a different, older version of Android Studio. Where is the "manifests" folder and AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest folder is automatically created when a new project is started in Android Studio.

It is likely you need to change the 'view mode' in the project window. You have some options:

Option 1:

1. Navigate to the Project Window. (You can press "Alt + 1" (win/nix) / "Command + 1" (mac) on your keyboard OR go to View --> Tool Windows --> Project.)
2. From there select the small drop down menu at the top left of the project window. It will likely say "Android", "Project" or "Packages".
3. Select "Android".
4. Extend the "app" hierarchy. You should then see a "manifests" folder.

[image: Manifest Selection]

Option 2:

1. Press "Ctrl + Shift + N" (win/nix) / "Command + Shift + O" (mac).
2. Type "manifest".
3. You will see the manifest file listed.

Also try:

Reset the cache to rebuild the project hierarchy. Go to: File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Great thank you! Option 2 works, but when trying option 1 there is just no "manifests" folder at all. Odd.

Comment: @mo3bius You are most welcome! I have added an image to show some details about selecting the correct view. It will be there, just have a click around. (: Please accept this answer, cheers! Best of luck!

Comment: @mo3bius - Another thought. Try resetting the cache. File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart .

Comment: Resetting the cache worked! "Manifests" folder now present. Also appears to have resolved an issue where I wasn't able to view the contents of activity_main.xml? Thanks again!